# SQL Sum and Group on two tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm incredibly new to SQL and working on completing some assignments in order to advance my knowledge.  I found myself stuck on a problem, though.
I have to find the total profit on items by using multiplication and subtraction, which I have completed with the following commands:

```
select 
   production.product.ProductID, 
   StandardCost, 
   sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty, 
   UnitPrice,
   (sales.SalesOrderDetail.UnitPrice*sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty)-
   (production.product.StandardCost*sales.salesorderdetail.OrderQty) as 
   'Total Profit'
from 
     sales.SalesOrderDetail, 
     production.product
```

What I need to do is sum the total profit and group it by the ProductID in order to find the most profitable items and the least profitable.  I thought this would work:

```
select 
     production.product.ProductID, 
     StandardCost, 
     sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty, 
     UnitPrice,
     sum((sales.SalesOrderDetail.UnitPrice*sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty)-
     (production.product.StandardCost*sales.salesorderdetail.OrderQty)) as 
     'Total Profit'
from 
    sales.SalesOrderDetail, 
    production.product
group by 
    Production.Product.ProductID
```

However, I receive the following error:

Column 'production.product.StandardCost' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I'm at a loss on where to continue.  I tried rearranging and doing inner/left joins, but I've been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for grouping you need to aggregate or include in the group by statement.
you are grouping by the productID but the other columns are not aggregated and are not in the group by statement.

a correction could be (depending on how you want to aggregate the other columns)

```
select 
  production.product.ProductID
  , avg(StandardCost) as AvgCost
  , sum(sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty) as TotalQuantity
  , avg(UnitPrice) as AvgUnitPrice
  , sum((sales.SalesOrderDetail.UnitPrice*sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty)-
        (production.product.StandardCost*sales.salesorderdetail.OrderQty)) as [Total Profit]
from sales.SalesOrderDetail
, production.product
group by Production.Product.ProductID
```